# Windows Server AppFabric Cache Time-out based invalidation callback

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I am using Windows Server AppFabric Caching in our application with local cache enabled.
This is configured as following:

```
<localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="1000" ttlValue="120"/>
```

I have setup time-out based invalidation with time-out interval of 120 seconds.
As per this configuration, local cache will remove items from in-memory cache after every 120 seconds and retrieve item from cache cluster. Is it possible to add a callback which gets fired whenever local cache tries to hit the cache cluster to retrieve items instead of fetching them locally?

Comment: Do you know what the default ttlValue is if it is not provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to know if data is fetched locally or not. There are cache server notifications but they are not reliable.

In your scenario, a good approach could be the Read-Through and Write-Behind feature. It does not fit to all situations but your can take a quick look.

Here are some links :

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377669.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prathul/archive/2011/12/06/appfabric-cache-read-from-amp-write-to-database-read-through-write-behind.aspx